# How to use one condition at multiple places in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have the following form in my angular project:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" validate-onblur aria-label="email">
<div *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['username'].pristine && loginForm.controls['username'].dirty && loginForm.controls['username'].hasError('required')">
    <p class="error-msg">{{messages.EMAIL_REQ}}</p>
</div>
```

The condition in the `<div>` tag in `ngIf`, I want to use this same condition in the `<input>` tag above, to add a class to that element, how can I achieve this?
Something like this (`myCondition`):

```
<input ngClass="{'error': myCondition}" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" validate-onblur aria-label="email">
<div *ngIf="myCondition">
    <p class="error-msg">{{messages.EMAIL_REQ}}</p>
</div>
```

I am new to angular so don't know if it possible or not.

I thought of creating a function in the component and calling this function with `onblur` attribute, but with this approach I have to create several functions, because the form has several fields with their specific conditions.

So how can I do this in the html file itself?

Comment: if your input has a formControlName or formControl, Angular makes the work for you: see the docs:https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, you could wrap the elements in a `<ng-container>` tag and extract the condition using `*ngIf` directive. It's commented out in the final rendered DOM.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="({res: (!loginForm.controls['username'].pristine && loginForm.controls['username'].dirty && loginForm.controls['username'].hasError('required'))}) as cond">
  <input type="email" [class.error]="cond.res" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" validate-onblur aria-label="email">
  <div *ngIf="cond.res">
    <p class="error-msg">{{messages.EMAIL_REQ}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

I've also replaced `[ngClass]` with `[class.error]`.

---

Although it's tempting to ignore the object in the `*ngIf` like

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(!loginForm.controls['username'].pristine && loginForm.controls['username'].dirty && loginForm.controls['username'].hasError('required')) as cond">
  ...
</ng-container>
```

it would counter-intuitive as the `<input>` would not be rendered when the condition is `false`. Wrapping it in an object would ensure the elements inside would be rendered even if the outer `*ngIf` in the `<ng-container>` would be `false`.